# Swagger Codegen use existing class

Tags: swagger-codegen

How can I get the swagger codegen to use an existing class instead of creating a new class? Is this possible? For instance I want to use `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` instead of swagger creating another page class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use `--import-mappings`, as it is explained [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#bringing-your-own-models):

> Sometimes you don't want a model generated. In this case, you can
>   simply specify an import mapping to tell the codegen what not to
>   create. When doing this, every location that references a specific
>   model will refer back to your classes.

You call this on `swagger-codegen-cli generate`, with the example you included it would be

`--import-mappings Page=org.springframework.data.domain.Page`

Although `importMappings` hasn't been included in the general configuration parameters [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) if you look at the code [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/plugin/CodeGenMojo.java#L184) you can see it's a `List<String>`.
I haven't used it with the maven plugin but looking at the doc and the code I'm guessing this should work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ...
            <configuration>
                ...
                <importMappings>
                   <importMapping>Page=org.springframework.data.domain.Page</importMapping>
                </importMappings>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But this was [recently changed](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/commit/165c11666162381992fe743ad5278243502ec9a2), so it might be different if you're using an older version of the plugin. Before that changed it seems to be like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ...
            <configuration>
                ...
                <configOptions>
                   <import-mappings>Page=org.springframework.data.domain.Page;Some=org.example.Some</import-mappings>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

According to the comment in that commit the old version should be supported too, but I haven't tried any of this so let me know if it works.

Comment: Ahh thank you. Do you know how I configure this with the swagger code-gen maven plugin?

Comment: I have updated how to use it based on the code, I haven't tried it, so it might not work. But at least if gives you an idea of where to look for it.

Comment: Thanks for that yeah I got to that stage in my Pom, I find that swagger is a bit dumb it just doesn't create a class for Page and it misses the`import org.springframework.data.domain.Page` so I have to edit template files manually anyway. You also can't change the name of your class so I cant have a Page for resource A and resource B is the same swagger file. haha, man I am going to submit an issue on github haha.

Comment: In that case add a link to the issue in the question just in case someone is looking for this

Comment: How would you make reference of `Page` in your yml file?

Comment: @Rapster just as if it was a common component of type object named `Page`

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it worked with `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter`, but feels like it doesn't :-/

Answer (score 19):

None of the answers mentioned here talked about what to add to the swagger yaml file,
in case someone is interested this is something that worked for me:

```
DisplayProperty:  
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
    displayName:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Text'
    isRequired:
      type: boolean
      example: false
Text:
    type: object
```

and then have this in the pom

```
<importMappings>
<importMapping>Text=com.--.--.--.--.Text</importMapping>
```

Comment: Seems like you missed the following yaml declarations before 'Text' in your example :
components:
  schemas:

Answer (score 8):

It's not always possible to use `--import-mappings` if you have long list of mappings.
(At least in case of Windows, which has size-limit for string in command prompt.)
That is why better way do it: use mapping with swagger configuration file.
(And this option is not fully documented.)

Like that:

`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate -i myspec.yaml -l java -c myconfig.json`

myconfig.json:

```
{
  "hideGenerationTimestamp": true,
  "dateLibrary": "java8",
  "useRuntimeException": true,
  "modelPackage": "org.my.package.model",
  "apiPackage": "org.my.package.api",
  "importMappings": {
    "Page": "org.springframework.data.domain.Page",
    "MySuperType": "org.my.SuperType"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me add that for the java generator you also have to specify an additional property ignoreImportMappings=false. For some reason, the default is to ignore the import mappings with that generator. See [this issue report](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/10419).

Here is the configuration which works for me with the swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.45</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <language>java</language>
        <additionalProperties>
          <additionalProperty>ignoreImportMappings=false</additionalProperty>
        </additionalProperties>
        <importMappings>
          <importMapping>MyClass=com.blah.blah.MyClass</importMapping>
        </importMappings>
        ...
```

Refer to it in the yaml file as usual:

```
$ref: "#/components/schemas/MyClass"
```