# OpenApi Generator reference an external Object in YAML file specification With <importMappings> Dont work

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

Hello I am trying to generate my Api with OpenApi Generator maven plugin, but I wanted to use existing objects so as not to have to rewrite the same thing, so I read about  and tried to use it, the problem is that I don't understand why in the requestBody it doesn't reference The object that I put in it only does it in the responses and when it generates the code it looks like this:

[generated method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJmIL.png)

my pom:
[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1M55.png)

my .yaml:
[swagger.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsX8n.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612080/swagger-codegen-use-existing-class